# Parse Error in webpack's package.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-2

I have the following simple webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"); //LINE OF INTEREST

module.exports = {

    entry: ["./main.js"],
    output: {
        path: "./build",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
    ]
};
```

When I comment out the top line defining webpack, I get an error because I reference webpack when defining the ProvidePlugin. When I include that 1st line however I get the following cryptic error:

```
ERROR in (webpack)/package.json
Module parse failed: /var/www/html/node_modules/webpack/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
```

First of all, I'm unsure why my node_modules folder is my apache root directory. Second of all, why am I getting a parse error? Isn't the `package.json` file something that was installed via npm? How could there be syntax errors in it?

Answer (score 2):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const webpack = require("webpack"); 
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/, 
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

[Working Example](https://gist.github.com/kasiriveni/9f7158cff5995ffefb6ad76f3aac99fc) For more Information

Comment: @ thatidiotguy please look at the solution if need more information please let me know